# How do I render text on the page of other sites (once script planted)

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and trying to build a chat app like intercom.

How do i go about creating a popup on another page once my js script is planted??

I do it locally like so:

```
function Hide()
  {
   document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility="hidden";
  }
```

Comment: Explain more please

Comment: How to i show an element on another site once the put 
<script src="mywebiste.com/api.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many way to do it i'll explain the idea with some examples, let's go
Our code based on two functionalities:
1: `innerHtml = "<YOUR CODE/>";`  This property is for injecting the html in the element [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).
2: `document.getElementById("IdName")` This property is for selecting and element wich we will apply some functionalities, in our case is the property N°1 [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp).
3: `<div id="IdName"></div>` Here where we will append our html or text [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).
Now we start with some examples:
1st example:
API File:

```
function function_name(argument) {
    document.getElementById(argument).innerHTML = "<p>Paragraph example..</p>";
}
```

User File:

```
// first of all the user need to put a div with an attribute ID in his html where
//he want to append the html given by the API
    <div id="IdName"></div>
//after that he must call the specified function wich is in our case function_name() and put the ID as argument
    function_name("IdName"); // this will append the html in the div with the ID == IdName
```

Also you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("className");` in place of ID
2nd example:
In this case the user don't need to put any additional html or any other things; in this  example we will add our html into the body element wich is a necessary element in HTML page.

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Paragraph example..</p>";
```

Comment: thanks @Bilel, Are there any performance issues with appending to the body like `  document.body.innerHTML +='<div>``

Comment: so how do I make it universal without sacrificing performance? I need to show a little icon in the corner of ever page.

How does intercom do it? See screenshot here for example http://imgur.com/a/HzVhF

Comment: Use the div with id or class like that you don't detaches all existing DOM nodes

Comment: But how would that work universally? I won't know the sites div id's

Comment: check this one i think it will work fine for you 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML